# Busy Indicator on before load of application

Tags: sapui5

My app takes some time to load, so i want a busy indicator to keep running until entire app loads and then time out after the app has loaded. Is it possible to run busy indicator even before index.html is loaded, so that the users can see something is happening until the app finally loads.